# LastChild не работает, а lastElementChild работает

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Свойство `lastChild.innerHTML` выводит значение `undefined`, а вот `lastElementChild.innerHTML` значение выводит. Почему? Ведь на обучающих сайтах выводится значение. Подскажите.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>New Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="d">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Привет Мир!</p>
  <p>To be or not to be?</p>
 </div>
 <script>
  // выводит undefined
  document.write(document.getElementById('d').lastChild.innerHTML + '<br />');
  // выводит To be or not to be? 
  document.write(document.getElementById('d').lastElementChild.innerHTML);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что последний child в вашей верстке пустой TextNode, а lastElementChild возвращает ссылку на последний Element, которым TextNode не является.

Вот так последний child будет параграф:

```
<div id="d">
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Привет Мир!</p>
   <p>To be or not to be?</p></div>
```

UPD, на самом деле вот так выглядит:

```
<div id="d">
[TextNode nodeValue="\n  "]
<p>[TextNode nodeValue="Hello World!"]</p>
[TextNode nodeValue="\n  "]
<p>[TextNode nodeValue="Привет мир"]</p>
[TextNode nodeValue="\n  "]
<p>[TextNode nodeValue="To be or not to be?"]</p>     <-- lastElementChild
[TextNode nodeValue="\n"]                             <-- lastChild
</div>
```

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Дело не в лучше/хуже, а задаче и поддержки браузерами, lastElementChild — начиная от IE9.

Comment: Ну это проблема в коде, который оказался завязан на DOM структуру :]  В общем удачи в изучении